# AngularJS Animation function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, animation

I decided to take off jQuery library and to do my own functions.
I started with Animation because I need it.

So, I store the interval ID and other datas on Element Object, in animate function I can see the property, but in another function, with same element, I can't see my property.

How I can make them global or something?

https://jsbin.com/yeqawuzoxu/edit?html,output

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script>
        var app = angular.module( "test", [] );  

        app.run(function () {
            angular.element.prototype.animate = function (data,duration,transition,complete) {

                if ( ! this.length ) return false;
                if ( data.height === undefined ) return false;
                if ( Math.floor(duration) !== duration || typeof duration !== "number" ) return false;
                if ( duration <= 0 ) return false;

                var act_height = this[0].offsetHeight;
                var new_height = parseFloat(data.height.replace( /[^\d\.]*/g, ''));

                var element = this;

                element.Animation = [];
                element.Animation.start = new Date;
                console.log ( element );
                element.Animation.interval = setInterval(function() {
                    var timePassed = new Date - element.Animation.start
                    var progress = timePassed / duration;

                    if (progress > 1) progress = 1;

                    var trans = ( Function.prototype.isPrototypeOf(complete) ) ? transition(progress) : progress;
                    element.css('height', (trans * (new_height-act_height)) + act_height + 'px');

                    if (progress == 1) {
                        console.log ( element );
                        if ( Function.prototype.isPrototypeOf(complete) ) complete();
                        clearInterval(element.Animation.interval);
                        element.Animation = null;
                        delete element.Animation;
                    }
                }, 10 );
            }
            angular.element.prototype.stop = function () {

                if ( ! this.length ) return false;
                console.log ( this );
            }            
        });

        app.directive('cacat', function() {
            return {
                restrict: 'E',
                link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                    element.css('float',  'left');
                    element.css('height', '100px');
                    element.css('width',  '100px');
                    element.css('background-color', 'black');
                    scope.anim = function ($event) {
                        if (! angular.element($event.target).hasClass('progress') ) {
                            angular.element($event.target).addClass('progress');
                            angular.element($event.target).animate({
                                height: '280px'   
                            }, 2000, function(t) { return t<.5 ? 4*t*t*t : (t-1)*(2*t-2)*(2*t-2)+1 }, function(){
                                angular.element($event.target).removeClass('progress');
                            });
                        } else {
                            angular.element($event.target).stop();
                        }
                    }
                }
            };
        });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body ng-app="test">
        <cacat ng-click="anim($event)"></cacat>
        <cacat ng-click="anim($event)"></cacat>
        <cacat ng-click="anim($event)"></cacat>
        <cacat ng-click="anim($event)"></cacat>        
    </body>
</html>
```

Press on one box, wait a while (to the middle maybe) and click again. After this wait to animation stop.
You will see in console the same element, but when you clicked in animation progress you will not see the property Animation.

Comment: Please include relevant code in your question, do not rely on links to outside sites to show code.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what type of solution you are after, but maybe $rootScope could be used to share data in this case. Link: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope Alternatively providers such as services and factories could work as well. More info: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers + Great Example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21919962/share-data-between-angularjs-controllers Anyway you got a cool code snippet at jsbin :-)

Comment: @jyrkim do you can give me an example for rootScope ?

Comment: oh man tried a bit with $apply and $rootScope but I couldn't get it working, I think it gets tricky when you mix ordinary AngularJS with other libraries. Good Luck :-)

Comment: I fixed, I used attribute for interval, the others variables are scoped.

Comment: excellent that you found a solution :-)